# Why can't I read this XML values with XElement?

Tags: xml, linq

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>51.84750492</longitude>
            <latitude>61.85536484</latitude>
            <range>4423610</range>
        </LookAt>
        <Style id="Filled_Label">
        </Style>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

And this is the code:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("/kml/MyFile2.kml");
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.opengis.new/kml/2.2");

var query = from x in doc.Elements(ns + "longitude")
            select x;

Response.Write(query.Count());

foreach (XElement item in query)
{
    Response.Write(item.Value);
}
```

but it does print nothing (0 elements).
Where am I wrong?

Comment: You have a typo in your namespace literal: `.new/kml` instead of `.net/kml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues that I see in the code you've posted.

## Typo in the namespace

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.opengis.new/kml/2.2");
```

On this line, you have `...opengis.new`, when I suspect you mean `...opengis.net`. Easy fix.

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
```

## Searching child nodes

```
var query = from x in doc.Elements(ns + "longitude")
            select x;
```

From what I can tell, you're using `Elements` when you want [`Descendants`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants(v=vs.110).aspx). `Elements()` looks only at the immediate children of the node, so in your case, that will look only for `Documents`, and find that your parameter doesn't match.

Change it to,

```
var query = from x in doc.Descendants(ns + "longitude")
            select x;
```

and it should work.

Granted, I tend to prefer to use a series of `Elements` calls, because `Descendants` can have some nasty side-effects. It'll take any elements, obviously, with that name, so it will return any that appear in the schema, whether they're what you want or not. So it really depends on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As collaspar already mentioned, you have a typo in your namespace:

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
```

You should also use  `XElement.Descendants` to get the *longitude*:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("/kml/MyFile2.kml");
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");

var query = doc.Descendants(ns + "longitude").Select(x => x);
```

If you want the value of the element, you can use this:

```
var values = query.Select(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("/kml/MyFile2.kml")
    XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");

    var query = doc.Descendants(ns + "longitude");
        //from x in doc.Elements(ns + "longitude")
             //   select x;

  //  Response.Write(query.Count());

    foreach (XElement item in query)
    {
       // Response.Write(item.Value);
    }
```